Why the program is ending abruptly
I need to solve a transcendental equation in C++ using Octave API, but the program crashes. Maybe there is a problem with indexes?
Code:
#include <iostream>
#include <octave/oct.h>
#include <octave/octave.h>
#include <octave/parse.h>
#include <octave/interpreter.h>

int main() {
    // Define the equation as a string
    std::string equation = "(2*x-3)^(2/3) - (x-1)^(2/3)";

    // Construct the Octave command to solve the equation
    std::string command = "fsolve(@(x) " + equation + ", 0)";

    // Parse and evaluate the Octave command
    octave_value_list retval = octave::feval ("eval", octave_value (command));

    // Extract the solution from the Octave output
    double solution = retval(0).double_value();

    // Print the solution
    std::cout << "Solution: x = " << solution << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

Compile:
g++ -o trans trans.cpp -I/usr/include/octave-6.4.0 -I/usr/include/octave-6.4.0/octave -I/usr/include/octave-6.4.0/octave/interpreter -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/octave-6.4.0/octave -I/usr/include/octave-6.4.0/octave/octave-config.h -loctave -loctinterp -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/octave/6.4.0 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/octave/6.4.0 -Wl,--no-as-needed -loctave -loctinterp
cc1plus: warning: /usr/include/octave-6.4.0/octave/octave-config.h: not a directory

Error:

Аварийный останов (образ памяти сброшен на диск)

which translates to “Emergency stop (memory image flushed to disk)” according to Google Translate.
I was able to solve an algebraic equation using the example of finding the roots of a polynomial, but is it possible to solve transcendental equations like in my code above?

-I/usr/include/octave-6.4.0/octave/octave-config.h  is a bug.  Instead of specifying a header file with -I you are supposed to specify the folder that the header is in. This is the reason for the warning but I will say its not your problem although you should fix it anyways.

Does this answer your question? What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?

The only occurrence search engines find of "Emergency stop (memory image reset to disk)" is this question, which is very odd.

Did you by any chance translate the error message yourself to English? If so, please also include the original text. Even if we don’t understand the language, we’d at least know where the message came from. Your translation is not useful on its own. I think this is a “segmentation error (core dumped)” error?

This is reason why I never use localization. Messages of compilers and OS services are always translated by seat of pants and you never can back translate them.

Here's the error in the original language:
Аварийный останов (образ памяти сброшен на диск)

I’m assuming you’re getting a segmentation error. Because you are indexing into an empty array.
In Octave, eval doesn’t return anything. So octave_value_list retval = octave::feval ("eval", octave_value (command)); is an empty list. retval[0] doesn’t exist.
Don’t use eval. It’s evil.
But for simplicity, this is how you’d use it:
std::string command = "res = fsolve(@(x) " + equation + ", 0)";
octave::feval("eval", octave_value(command));
octave_value_list retval = octave::feval("res");

(code not tested.)

Tried the code according to your changes and the error is still the same:
Аварийный останов (образ памяти сброшен на диск)

@zoow then there must be some other problem in addition to this one. Have you run the program through the debugger? Have you at least added some print statements to see which lines are executing and where the error happens? It is really impossible for us to debug something on your machine, you will have to do this yourself.
